# Python/Pandas:How does one pivot a table whereby the unique values in a specified multi -index or column form part of the resultant column name?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pivot a pandas table composed of 3 columns whereby the process id identifies the process that generates a series of scalar values, forms part of the resultant dataframe column (per process) as the following describes:

Input

```
time     scalar     process_id
1        0.5        A
1        0.6        B
2        0.7        A
2        1.5        B
3        1.6        A
3        1.9        B
```

Resultant:

```
time     scalar_A     scalar_B
1        0.5          0.6
2        0.7          1.5
3        1.6          1.9
```

I have tried using unstack (after setting process id in a multi index), however this causes the columns and process id that generated them to be nested:

```
bicir.set_index(['time', 'process_id'], inplace=True)
df.unstack(level=-1)
```

How would one most efficiently/effectively achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: `final=df.unstack(level=-1).head()` then 
`final.columns=[f"{a}_{b}"for a,b in final.columns]`, and finally
`final.reset_index()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually already covered by [pd.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) method:

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='time', columns='process_id', values='scalar').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
process_id  time    A    B
0              1  0.5  0.6
1              2  0.7  1.5
2              3  1.6  1.9
```

And if you want to rename your columns:

```
new_df = df.pivot(index='time', columns='process_id', values='scalar')
new_df.columns = [f'scalar_{i}' for i in new_df.columns]
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   time  scalar_A  scalar_B
0     1       0.5       0.6
1     2       0.7       1.5
2     3       1.6       1.9
```